# Match integer to numeric range in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, match

Assume three non-overlapping numeric ranges of integers (*r1*, *r2* and *r3*) as well as one target integer *i*.

```
i = 7
ranges = {"r1": [0,4], "r2": [5,8], "r3": [9,10]}
```

What function would return me the dictionary key (i.e., the name of the numeric range) in whose range the target integer falls?

```
sought_function(i, ranges)
# "r2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a list comprehension iterating over [dictionary items](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) and checking the `i` to be in range:

```
>>> i = 7
>>> ranges = {"r1": [0,4], "r2": [5,8], "r3": [9,10]}
>>> [key for key, (low, high) in ranges.iteritems() if low <= i <= high]
['r2']
```

<sup>Using `iteritems()` since the question is tagged with `Python-2.7`.</sup>

If you need the first value only, use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> next(key for key, (low, high) in ranges.iteritems() if low <= i <= high)
'r2'
```

Note that if there are no values matching the condition, you would get `StopIteration` exception. You may either handle the error, of provide a *default value* if it makes sense in your case.

Comment: Your first example code, while very readable, doesn't pass the following test: `for i in range(0,11):  [key for key, (low, high) in ranges.iteritems() if low < i < high]`. Note: i=11 was included deliberately to provoke exception.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl do you mean I should've included the range boundaries too? Updated. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl, 11 is not in `range(0,11)`, range is half open.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Yes, you are quite right of course. My bad.

Comment: @alecxe Thank you for updated code. Good short and succinct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If ranges can be repated/overlapping

```
iranges = [x for x, r in ranges.items() if r[0] <= i <= r[1]]
```

If there can be only one or None

```
irange = next((x for x, r in ranges.items() if r[0] <= i <= r[1]), None)
```

`items` gives you compatibility with Python 3 ... should you need it

Comment: Both of your example codes generally pass my test of `for i in range(0,11): your_code_here`. It should be noted that the first example code returns a list (with one list item), while the second one returns a string. (Neither example throws an error when i is outside the ranges - but I realize that this was not specified in my question.)

Comment: The "not found" condition are an empty `list` (first case) and `None` (second case)